# Pass object from VC to App Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a few objects in a VC that I want to be accessible from my App Delegate.

My VC launches another app, which does a callback to my app.  This callback triggers a method in my App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

But I want to access some objects in this method that I had set in that previous VC.  Any ideas how?

Comment: You are launching another _app_, and this new app is calling methods back in your original app? This seems to violate sand boxing - is it really what you are doing?

Comment: is it possible to share data between two applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
+(id)sharedApplicationDelegate; in delegate.h, and write

+(id)sharedApplicationDelegate{
    return  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

In delegate.m. Make object data type variable in .h and set its property.
Write a method like this:

```
-(void)setObjectForDelegate:(ObjectType *)value{
//use value obj or set it to other variable
}
```

How to Use:

```
#import “XXXXdelegate.h”
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setObjectForDelegate:object];
```