# How to send text from text field to another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm making an app that behaves something like the default Messages.app in iPhone where a user composes a text message in a `UITextField` and upon tapping the Send button, the value of the `UITextField` in `ComposeViewController` will be transferred to the table cell's `UILabel` in a custom cell in `MasterViewController` and also to the `DetailViewController` where another `UILabel` will get the text value from the `UITextField`. The `DetailViewController` is the `ViewController` loaded when the user taps the cells from the `UITableViewCells`.

I actually read related articles below but it doesn't work on my end.

- How to send the text from textfield to another class?
- How to see text from one text field in another text field?
- How to send text field value to another class

Can you please guide me on how to properly implement this? I know it's easy. I just don't know why it's not working. ComposeVC is a `ModalViewController` while DetailVC is the view that loads when the user taps the cell in the MasterVC's table.

Thanks a lot!

Below is my code for ComposeVC.h:

```
    UITextField *messageTextField;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *messageTextField;

    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

for ComposeVC.m

```
    synthesize messageTextField;

    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        DetailVC *detailVC = [[DetailVC alloc] init];
        detailVC.messageText = messageTextField.text;
    }
```

for DetailVC.h

```
    NSString *messageText;

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *messageText;
```

for DetailVC.m

```
    @synthesize messageText;

    - (void)viewLoad
    {
        testLabel.text = messageText;
    }
```

testLabel is the UILabel inside my DetailVC.

Comment: Look this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162777/pass-object-from-vc-to-app-delegate/8163590#8163590

Comment: Thanks but it just confused me more. All I need is to pass the value from the UITextField onto other VCs just like in Messages.app where you compose a text message on a ModalVC and the text value is passed to the cell and the message bubbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create property on another viewController. Suppose your textField is on view1 and you want to send it on view2 then:

in view 2
.h file

```
#interface view2:UIViewController {
NSString *str;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

in .m file
    @synthesize str;

Now you can send your text from view1 to view 2 like:

```
objView2.str = txtField.text;
```

For viewing one textfield's text in another use
   secondTextField.text = firstTextField.text;

Hope this helped let me know if you are looking for something different.

Comment: I edited my question above. Please see changes. So far, your answer is the closest one yet. Thanks in advance. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I think it works because my testLabel turned blank. Any suggestions why it's like that?

Comment: Have you mapped your testLabel from your interface builder by creating IBOutlet?

Comment: This is ok now. All I was looking for is NSUserDefaults. I just used it and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#interface SecondView:UIViewController 
{
    NSString *stringSecond;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

In First View u have to create an reference like this:

```
#import "SecondView.h"

SecondView *detailViewController = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

detailViewController.stringSecond = @"Some string";
```

Comment: It's the same with the answer above but it still appears blank.

Comment: I think u are not allocate memory for the String Variable.    
detailViewController.stringSecond=[NSStringalloc]init];                detailViewController.stringSecond=@"Some string";

Answer (score 0):

take one variable in the app delegate like in appdelegate.h

```
@interface appdelegate
{
NSString *str1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

In .m file synthesize it.

set the text after editing the textfield(app del.str=textfield.text i.e setting value).And use the same wherever you want.

```
NSString *str = appdel.str(getting value);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get it.